# Convert UIColor to CCNodeColor

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsstring, uicolor, ccnode

As I'm passing `NSString`s into `UIColor`s and what not, for my cocos2d application, I am storing a colour for the scene's background in a `UIColor` variable, however would like to then convert the `UIColor` to a `CCNodeColor` variable? Obviously, the sample code below is wrong but that's where I'm at right now.

```
NSString *backgroundColour = [backgroundColourArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
CIColor *coreColour = [CIColor colorWithString:backgroundColour];
UIColor *colour = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColour];
CCNodeColor *background = [UIColor colour]; // Problems arise here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create CCNodeColor like this:

```
CCNodeColor *background = [[CCNodeColor alloc] initWithColor:[CCColor colorWithUIColor:colour]];
```